# modify HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP showing proxy IP instead true IP

Tags: http-proxy

I setup ProxyPass & ProxyPassReverse. But the website I need to access still detect my real IP (my ISP IP) instead my proxy server IP. What I notice is HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP showing my real IP. Is there a way to modify so that it detect my proxy server IP.

I unset the X-Forwarded-For and able to change the IP except HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP

SSLProxyEngine On
SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off
SSLProxyVerify none
SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
ProxyRequests On
ProxyAddHeaders Off
ProxyPass / https://otherwebsite.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://otherwebsite.com/
ProxyPassReverseCookiePath / /
ProxyPassReverseCookieDomain .otherwebsite.com .myproxy.com

    AddOutputFilterByType SUBSTITUTE text/html
    Substitute "s/otherwebsite.com/myproxy.com/ni"
    RequestHeader unset Accept-Encoding
    RequestHeader unset X-Forwarded-For

Comment: the https://otherwebsite.com/ only allow my proxy server (myproxy.com) IP to access their content, and when I using my computer to access myproxy.com and it detect my IP address instead my proxy IP address.
HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR show my proxy IP
but HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP show my computer IP

Comment: Oh I see - so you want it to see the proxy address? So the problem is that the request you're forwarding onto it still has the HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP header set and it's using that as the client IP address not the proxy, so what you want to do is `unset CF-Connecting-IP`? Is that enough, or do you need to set it to some other value as well - the old X-Forwarded-For address? `RequestHeader set CF-Connecting-IP expr=%{HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR}` ?